# Windows 10 does not show "Always available offline" for my SMB network drive

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi, smb, network-drive

I'm on Windows 10. I have connected a drive shared by a Raspberry Pi via SMB as a network drive. Access via Windows File Explorer works both for reading and writing. However, I can't seem to make it "Always available offline". Neither is there such an entry in the drive's conext menu nor is the option available in the "Properties" dialog of the drive.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

may I ask which method you use to access the shared drive? Do you use "\ip" or "\host name"?

To turn on offline files in Windows 10, there are 3 common used ways. You can try one of them in the following.

Method 1: Configure offline files in Windows 10 by Sync Center

Method 2: Enable offline files in Windows 10 using GPO

Method 3: Enable Offline Files in Windows 10 using Registry

For more details, please refer to:
https://www.ubackup.com/windows-10/enable-offline-files-windows-10.html